# How can I migrate specific, entire schemas from one Postgres database to another using pgloader?

Tags: postgresql, migration, schema, database-migration, pgloader

I want to migrate multiple entire schemas (but not every schema) from Postgres database *A* to Postgres database *B*, replacing the existing schemas in *B*. Is this possible using [pgloader](https://pgloader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/pgsql.html), without having to specify in the command file all of the relations and objects within each schema?

These schema contents change frequently in the development lifecycle, but the set of schemas that need to be migrated rarely changes, so it would be ideal for the command file to not be tightly coupled to the schema contents.

I searched the pgloader documentation, Google and `pgloader --help` but was unable to find the answer.

Comment: Why not use `pg_dump` switch `--schema=pattern` per docs here [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html). Though beware that will not dump cross schema referenced objects.

Comment: In general and for simple cases this is a good way to go. My current script is using `pg_dump`, but I've run into issues with it that a full-featured ETL tool might be able to address. I'm also trialing `pgloader` as a possible replacement for our large collection of idiosyncratic, brittle roll-your-own ETL scripts across several projects, to reduce the cost of maintaining our multiple "reinventions of the wheel". My hope is that a `pgloader` can do this kind of operation along with others in a single command file and not leave the db in a mysterious partially synced state if it fails.